# Segmentation fault while trying to get value from another class object

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have created few classes to introduce my problem. I am getting the `segmentation fault` error while I am trying to get data from objects whose pointers are in `Storage` class. This program hold the single pointer of `First` class type, which can hold `FirstChild` class object address. `FirstChild` class inherits from `First` class.

So, I have created two methods to get the data from the objects. First one (`getNumbers()`)is  the virtual method which is returning the value of the variables and the second one `getNum()` is calling the `getNumbers()` method.

The `segmentation fault` error means that I am trying to access to the memory that I do not have the access.

But is there the other way to get those values?

**First.h**

```
#ifndef FIRST_HPP
#define FIRST_HPP

class First {
  protected:
    int x;
  public:
    First(int x);
    virtual ~First();
    virtual int getNumbers();
 }

#endif
```

**First.cpp**

```
#include "First.h"

First::First(int x) : x(x){}
int First::getNumbers(){
  return this->x;
}
First::~First(){}
```

**FirstChild.h**

```
#ifndef FIRST_CHILD_HPP
#define FIRST_CHILD_HPP

class FirstChild : public First {
  private:
   int y;
  public:
    FirstChild(int x, int y);
    virtual int getNumbers();
 }

#endif
```

**FirstChild.cpp**

```
#include "FirstChild.h"

FirstChild::FirstChild(int x, int y) : First(x), y(y){}
int FirstChild::getNumbers() {
 return this->x + this->y; 
}
```

**Storage.h**

```
#ifndef STORAGE_HPP
#define STORAGE_HPP

#include "First.hpp"

class Storage {
  private:
    First * somePtr;
    int z;

  public:
    Storage(First * ptr);
    int getNum();
 }

#endif
```

**Storage.cpp**

```
#include "Storage.h"

Storage::Storage(First * ptr) {
this->somePtr = ptr;
}

int Storage::getNum(){
 return this->somePtr->getNumbers(); //Segmentation fault (core dumped)
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "First.h"
#include "FirstChild.h"
#include "Storage.h"

int main(){

First * firstPtr;
FirstChild FchObject(10);

firstPtr = &FchObject;

Storage storage(firstPtr);
storage.getNum();  //Segmentation fault

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually this is a sign you should pop this into your debugger to step up to the point of crashing and see why.

Comment: `Storage.getNum();` is not valid syntax. This shouldn't compile, so it can't crash.

Comment: Why does the signature of your `getNum()` implementation not match? How does any of this work?

Comment: I did that. I am using `gdb` debbuger. It shows "segmentation fault" in lines which I indicated.

Comment: To avoid confusion between classes and instances, try and keep your class names like `First` and your instance names like `first`.

Comment: Now you know where it crashes, that's great, but it means you need to step carefully to that point to find out *why*.

Comment: @tadman Because I forgot about the type of function in `storage.cpp`. Now it should be ok.

Comment: As @aschepler pointed out there's no way this compiles as-is even with that fix. That `main.cpp` is missing a *lot* of code.

Comment: But it compiles.

Comment: Does not compile - "FirstChild FchObject(10);",  error: no matching function for call to ‘FirstChild::FirstChild(int)’  ... The ctor you provided has two parameters.

Comment: @sqlMasterSOon [Prove that it compiles](https://www.ideone.com/).  If you still state that this obvious wrong code compiles, then this indicates that you are not understanding the code you're writing,  *Of course* an instance of the class must be created to call `getNum()`, but your code is oblivious of that fact, and you're not even seeing the wrongness (or the weirdness) of your code violating this rule.

Comment: Does not compile -  "Storage(firstPtr);" error: conflicting declaration ‘Storage firstPtr’,  ...........  clang says "error: redefinition of 'firstPtr' with a different type: 'Storage' vs 'First *'"

Comment: clang++ reports -  "warning: private field 'z' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]"

Comment: "But it compiles" -  what do you see to indicate a compile without errors?  Where do you expect the error messages to show ... might they be some other screen or window?  Tool? (g++ v?, clang++ v?) or Visual something or other?

Comment: there is no dynamic memory allocation here, tag is irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

Like others, I don't understand how this line compiles because getNum() in should require an instance:

```
Storage.getNum();  //Segmentation fault
```

Try this:

```
Storage myStorage(firstPtr);
myStorage.getNum();
```

Comment: I send the pointer to the instance in constructor of the `Storage` class.  I am executing the `getNum()` method on this pointer.

Comment: @sqlMasterSOon - No, you're not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot compile as-is, 3 syntax errors in main():

```
FirstChild FchObject(10);
```

Because constructor's signature is FirstChild(int x, int y), this must have two arguments, e.g.

```
FirstChild  FchObject(5, 10);
```

A proper declaration of variable missing for `Storage` class

```
firstPtr = &FchObject;
Storage  variable_name(firstPtr);
```

Non-static method's call would require an instance of class before . operator:

```
variable_name.getNum();
```